# How to create an instance of a child class with a factory builder using generics?

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, static, builder-pattern

I am trying to create an instance of a class using factory builder from the parent.

The use case is basically a library that contains series of classes that inherit from the same class.
The main goal was to reduce the amount of code in those classes.

I have an interface that contains two values, `IDualValues<T>`.

```cs
public interface IDualValues<T>
{
    public T FirstValue { get; }
    public T SecondValue { get; }
}
```

This is an example of what all the classes will look like (changing the method name).

```cs
public class Foo : IDualValues<string>
{
    public string FirstValue { get; }
    public string SecondValue { get; }

    public Foo(string firstValue, string secondValue)
    {
        FirstValue = firstValue;
        SecondValue = secondValue;
    }

    public static Foo Create(string firstValue, string secondValue)
    {
        return new Foo(firstValue, secondValue);
    }
}
```

My point is that I want to use the FactoryBuilder to do `Foo.Create` instead of a new instance directly in the client application.

The ideal scenario will have a parent class that contains all the logic:

```cs
public class DualValuesBuilder<T, CreatedType> : IDualValues<T>
where CreatedType : class, IDualValues<T>
{
    public T FirstValue { get; init; }
    public T SecondValue { get; init; }

    private DualValuesBuilder(T firstValue, T secondValue)
    {
        FirstValue = firstValue;
        SecondValue = secondValue;
    }

    public static CreatedType Create(T firstValue, T secondValue)
    {
       //Creation here
    }
}
```

and the other classes will be empty classes just implementing that one:

```cs
public class Foo : DualValuesBuilder<string, Foo>
{
}
```

Notice that I am sending the class itself as a generic parameter to the "builder".

To Achieve my goal, I created a "helper" class to build a class that inherits from `IDualValues<T>`.

```cs
public class DualValuesBuilderHelper<T> : IDualValues<T>
{
    public T FirstValue { get; init;}
    public T SecondValue { get; init; }

    private DualValuesBuilderHelper(T firstValue, T secondValue)
    {
        FirstValue = firstValue;
        SecondValue = secondValue;
    }

    public static IDualValues<T> Create<ReturnType>(T developerK8SClusterValue, T octopusValue)
    where ReturnType : IDualValues<T>
    {
        return new DualValuesBuilderHelper<T>(developerK8SClusterValue, octopusValue);
    }
}
```

and then I updated the `Create` method in the class `DualValuesBuilder` to look like the next:

```cs
public static CreatedType Create(T firstValue, T secondValue)
{
    return (CreatedType)DualValuesBuilderHelper<T>.Create<CreatedType>(firstValue, secondValue);
}
```

But that is giving me an error on the casting:
`System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'DualValuesBuilderHelper`1[System.String]' to type 'Foo'.`

Here there is a fiddle with the code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IUrgr1

Yes, if I do the following works, but is not what I am trying to achieve.

```cs
Foo foo = new Foo()
{
    FirstValue = "f1",
    SecondValue = "f2"
};
```

note: Using the construtor also works, but I need to make it work with the `Create`.

Even if I create an explicit (or implicit) operator, the casting still happening.

Am I  overthinking, and there is a simple way of accomplishing what I am trying to do?
Or is it not possible to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated as I'd missed the nuance of the inherited factory method.

Primarily adding `new()` to the generic constraint will sort you out, and including `CreateType` must be a child of `DualValuesBuilder`: `where CreateType : DualValuesBuilder<CreateType, DataType>, new()`

```
public interface IDualValues<T>
{
    public T FirstValue { get; init; }
    public T SecondValue { get; init; }
}

public class Foo : DualValuesBuilder<Foo, string>
{
}

public class Foo2 : DualValuesBuilder<Foo2, int>
{
}
    
public class DualValuesBuilder<CreateType, DataType> : IDualValues<DataType>
    where CreateType : DualValuesBuilder<CreateType, DataType>, new()
{
    public DataType FirstValue { get; init; }
    public DataType SecondValue { get; init; }

    public static CreateType Create(DataType firstValue, DataType secondValue)
    {
        return new CreateType
        {
            FirstValue = firstValue,
            SecondValue = secondValue
        };
    }
}
```

---

Primarily adding `new()` to the generic constraint will sort you out:         `where CreatedType : class, IDualValues<T>, new()`

```
public interface IDualValues<T>
{
    public T FirstValue { get; init; }
    public T SecondValue { get; init; }
}

public class Foo : IDualValues<string>
{
    public string FirstValue { get; init; }
    public string SecondValue { get; init; }
}

public static class DualValuesBuilder
{
    public static CreateType Create<CreateType, DataType>(
        DataType firstValue, 
        DataType secondValue)
        where CreateType : class, IDualValues<DataType>, new()
    {
        return new CreateType
        {
            FirstValue = firstValue,
            SecondValue = secondValue
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I cannot do `Foo.Create() ` I have to do `Foo foo = DataValuesBuilder.Create()`.

Comment: @TiGreX why do you need abstract static builder method in a specific class? As for me, it doesn't make much sense. Approach suggested by `@qujck` is better in terms of code decoupling and produces more testable code

Comment: @AndrewSilver the problem with that approach is that is not readable if a root type has 10 properties, it will be something like `Bar.Create(defaultvaluesbuilder.create(), defaultvaluesbuilder.create(),...` which is very hard to read (in a PR for example)  if you compare it with `Bar.Create(Foo.Create(), Another.Create(),...)`. and in top of that you "won't be using types" as everything is 'IDualVaules<T>`, Which will allow you to swap the parameters without compiling errors.